# String Parsing ,Full path of xml file ,c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

I need some help, please.

I want to  load data from the xml file , but i get an error message :
"Could not find file 'C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\MyApp\MyApp\MyData.xml'."

There is part of my code  :

```
string dataPath =AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "MyData.xml";
XDocument xmlItems = XDocument.Load(dataPath);
```

In debugging I see that dataPath has this value:

```
"C:\\Users\\someuser\\Desktop\\MyApp\\MyApp\\MyData.xml"
```

and I need

```
"C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\MyApp\MyApp\MyData.xml"
```

When I use the full path of the xml file it works fine.

Comment: I suspect you're being misled by the debugger performing extra escaping for you. Do you really intend to have `MyApp` in there twice? Can you show the code which works, specifying the full path?

Comment: don't use concatenation in path combining, use Path.Combine.

Comment: Same problem with Path.Combine , i need to set "\" instead "\\"

Comment: If I set the full path :                                           List<Item> lItems = new List<Item>();
//string[] dataPath ={"@",AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MyData.xml"};
//string fullPath = Path.Combine(dataPath);
XDocument xmlItems = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\MyApp\MyApp\MyData.xml");   In this way it works

Comment: @user2381509 doesn't the error message already show that it's been looking for the correct path?